# Paginador homemade Javascript no funciona como necesito

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un paginador de datos, pero ya me atoré. Tengo dos problemas.
Quiero que salte de 10 en 10 elementos y lo hace de 20 en 20, no se por qué.
Necesito ponerle un límite, o sea que no me traiga todos a partir de un índice dado, si no que me traiga apartir de dicho índice sólo 10, o lo que se marque como tamaño de la página, pero me sigue trayendo todo.

Estoy un poco confundido con `array.slice` dejo un ejemplo de lo que tengo hecho.

```js
const arr = Array.from( Array( 100 ).keys() );
let currentPage = 0;


const pageSize = Number( document.getElementById('pagesize').value ) || 10;

const change = ( num ) => {
  
  currentPage += num;
  if( currentPage < 0 ) {
    currentPage = 0;
    
  } else if ( currentPage > Math.ceil( ( arr.length / pageSize ) ) ) {
    currentPage = Math.ceil( ( arr.length / pageSize ) );
    
  } else {
    currentPage += num;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = arr.slice( ( pageSize * currentPage ) );
 
};
```

```html
<input id="pagesize" value="10">
<button onClick="change(-1)">Menos</button>
<button onClick="change(1)">Más</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error al usar [`array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) es que estas omitiendo indicar el `fin`.

### Solución:

En lo personal prefiero establecer mi `currentPage` igual al número que debería visualizar el usuario, es decir, **no empezaría en `0` sino en `1`**

Además validaría que `currentPage * pageSize` no supere el largo del arreglo.

Por último quedaría calcular `from` y `to` (*desde y hasta*) y utilizarlos en `slice`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 100}, (v, i) => i + 1);
let currentPage = 1;
const pageSize = Number(document.getElementById('pagesize').value) || 10;

const change = (num) => {

  currentPage += num;
  if (currentPage < 1) {
    currentPage = 1;
  } else if ((currentPage * pageSize) > arr.length) {
    currentPage = Math.ceil(arr.length / pageSize);
  }

  let from = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
  let to = from + pageSize;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = arr.slice(from, to);

};
```

```html
<input id="pagesize" value="10">
<button onClick="change(-1)">Menos</button>
<button onClick="change(1)">Más</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = Array.from( Array( 100 ).keys() );
let currentPage = 0;


const pageSize = Number( document.getElementById('pagesize').value ) || 10;

const change = ( num ) => {

  currentPage += num;
  if( currentPage < 0 ) {
    currentPage = 0;
  } else if ( currentPage > Math.ceil(arr.length / pageSize) ) {
    currentPage = Math.ceil(arr.length / pageSize);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = arr.slice(pageSize * currentPage);
 
};
```

```html
<input id="pagesize" value="10">
<button onClick="change(-1)">Menos</button>
<button onClick="change(1)">Más</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

El método `.slice()` es idéntico a `.substring()`, es decir, extrae una cadena desde el indice `[start]` hasta el índice `[end - 1]`. El parámetro `[end]` es opcional y si se omite extrae hasta el final.

En este caso estarías extrayendo toda tu cadena porque solo le indicas el primer valor en pocas palabras.

Ahora bien la razón de tu error es que agregas dos veces el `currentPage += num` en dos ocasiones, una al principio de la función y la otra en tus condiciones de if en el ultimo else, las condiciones hacen que tu variable cumpla la condición  y en dos ocasiones agregue num al final de tu operación por lo cual en lugar de multiplicar `pageSize* currentPage` que te debería de dar como resultado 10 te da 20 en su lugar ya que currentPage al final de la operación vale 2.

De acuerdo con tus condicionales el primer if nunca se ejecutara debido a que el valor de `currenPage` no es menor a cero en ningún momento, `currenPage` tampoco es mayor a `Math.ceil(arr.length/pageSize)` porque esto equivale a 10 y por ultimo esta tu condición de `currentPage += num` en tu ultima condición la cual si se ejecuta.